# Website or tool for timing other language subtitles based on a properly timed but different language one?

Tags: subtitles

I sometimes get in a situation, when I have an already properly timed subtitles for a video and I have a different language subtitle file, which I would like to synchronize to the existing one. Usually it can not be done easily, because the other language subtitles can not be paired with the proper one (eg.: other language used different partitioning of the sentences, or some of the sentences simply wasn't translated, etc). Furthermore sometimes linear stretching or compression of the subtitles timings don't work (tool for this purpose available on this website: http://subtitlefix.com under the 2 in 1 section). In this case one have to determine 2 pairs of corresponding subtitle lines, and then solving a linear equation, an "a" and a "b" value is computed, with whom the timing data are transformed according to an a*t+b linear equation, where "t" is the time.

For problematic cases even this method don't work well. What other automatic, and semi-automathic tools, techniques should taken into consideration for such scenarios?